# Specific image link

Tags: views, media, display-suite

I use Display Suite and Views in contents. I have got Galleria fullscreen theme in full content.

Drupal's images link options are "Linked to content" and "linked to URL"; I want that thumbnail images are linked to fullscreen images.

How can I do this?

Comment: [Colorbox](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox) is an option. There are others.

Comment: But i will use always Galleria fullscreen so must know another ways.

Comment: Galleria is your theme right ? So it shouldn't have anything to do with the way links behave, as it is more on the business logic side. Colorbox is well integrated with Views, so you should be able to format your lists of nodes (aka galleries if talking about pictures) with a link to a popup. Or to a page with full size pictures if you don"t want Colorbox behaviour. Perhaps I don't understand your needs, then you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: Listening my products on my site frontpage and its all image thumbnail and teaser mode. My product info is full content mode and use Galleria fullscreen theme. When i click thumbnail, i want go to this fullscreen page but Drupal 7 default image options, only "Linked to image" or "Linked to content" I want like this: "Linked to Galleria fullscreen"

Comment: Again, the links displayed depend on the page or view, not the theme, which only handles THE WAY they are displayed (styled). You have to tweak the product view to achieve what you want.